# Accessing data from another web application throws an SQLInvalidException

Tags: 2013, security, web-application, sql

The scenario is:

1. A MySiteHost site collection (example name: **MY SITE**). Web application's application pool account is *spmysite*.
2. A TeamSite site collection (example name: **TEAM SITE**). Web application's application pool account is *spteamsite*.
3. A webpart at **MY SITE** is retrieving data from **TEAM SITE**; specifically it's trying to retrieve SPGroups.
4. Hitting the following SQL Exception during data retrieval that **MY SITE**'s application pool account could not login to **TEAM SITE**'s content DB.

Tried:

1. Changing **MY SITE**'s application pool account to be the same as **TEAM SITE**'s (*spteamsite*). Data retrieval successful! But we have a requirement that different web applications must have different application pool accounts. :(
2. Changing **MY SITE**'s application pool account to the farm account (ex: *spfarm*). Data retrieval successful! But we have a requirement that we should not be using the farm account.
3. In **TEAM SITE**'s content DB, granted SPDataAccess or DBOwner role to *spmysite*. Unsuccessful. Side effect is in accessing **MY SITE**, it's hitting the "This website is not shared to you" error page (Cannot make sense).

We're pretty sure it's more of a configuration problem.

Appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way to grant access is to use the [SPWebApplication.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms478270.aspx) method. It sets up the database permissions for you, but remember to run it again if you add content databases.

You can do this with the following PowerShell:

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication TEAM_SITE_URL
$webApp.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity("domain\username of MY SITE pool account")
```